# Ember-data adding unnecessary records

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Let's say I have an app about animes..
I want to be able to access the same anime with any of the following urls:
`/a/foo/1`
`/a/foo`
`/a/1`
so my router is defined as following:

```
// router.js
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('animes', { path: '/a/' }, function() {
        this.route('add');
        this.route('remove');
    });
    this.resource('anime', { path: '/a/:anime_id' });
    this.resource('anime', { path: '/a/:slug/:anime_id' }, function() {
        this.route('edit');
    });
});
```

my `anime route` looks like this:

```
// routes/anime.js
var AnimeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        afterModel: function(anime, transition) {
            // redirect to the url /a/foo/1
        if(anime.get('slug') !== transition.params.anime.slug) {
            this.replaceWith('anime', anime);
        }
    },
    serialize: function(anime) {
        return {
            slug: anime.get("slug"),
            anime_id: anime.get("id")
        };
    } 
});

export default AnimeRoute;
```

My backend is configured to return the right data no matter if what was sent is an id or a slug.
There's no problem in the case of urls in the form of `/a/foo/1` and `/a/1`, but in the case of the url: `/a/foo`, the ember inspector shows that there's an additional record `{id: foo, title: undefined, slug: undefined, ...: undefined}`
how to fix this?

EDIT: here's a jsbin illustrating the problem: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rasewowapocu/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have this.resource('anime', { path: '/a/:anime_id' }); in your route map, /a/foo will match this one and suppose that foo is an id. Since your backend returns data no matter what was sent this probably messes things up.I guess it should work if you overwrite the model function of your AnimeRoute like this:

```
App.AnimeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function(params) {          
          var slug_or_id = params.anime_id;
          if(jQuery.isNumeric(slug_or_id)){ //id
                  return this.store.find('anime',slug_or_id);    
          }else{ //slug
                  return this.store.find('anime', { slug: slug_or_id }).then(function(a) {                      
                           return a.get('firstObject');
                  });   
          }          
    },
    afterModel: function(anime, transition) {
                // redirect to the url /m/foo/1
            if(anime.get('slug') !== transition.params.anime.slug) {
                this.replaceWith('anime', anime);
            }..
```

edit: added iguider hint to only return the first object.

Comment: already tried this, but I don't know what the backend should return when calling `this.store.find('anime', {slug:slug_or_id});`
I think it expects something like: `{animes: [{id:3, title:"Foo", slug:"foo"}]}` (note the pluralized animes and the array in response), which is not what I want

Comment: Indeed, when you use a parameter to find a model, your backend could return multiple models, hence the pluralized name. But do you still see the additional record with ember inspector? For the pluralization issue you can probably use Ember.Inflector.inflector: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_pluralization-customization

Comment: when you say: "your backend could return multiple models" do you mean that I have the choice to return a single record? if not, how to transform the array (containing one record) to a single record?

Comment: please edit your answer to the following so that I can accept it:
replace `return this.store.find('anime', {slug:slug_or_id})` by `return this.store.find('anime', { slug: slug_or_id }).then(function(a) {
    return a.get('firstObject');
   });`